# IntelliJ: How to use a main class which is not inside my Project Folder

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mainclass

I want to run a Project in IntelliJ, with a main class which is not inside my project folder. When I click the three dots to the right of the input, I can find this class (outside my project folder). However, once I run the project I get an error:

[image]

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.vertx.java.platform.impl.cli.Starter

What I understand is that IntelliJ is looking for the main class INSIDE the project folder, and therefore, it can't find it.

My question is how to make IntelliJ activate a main class outside the project folder.

**Edit:** I also tried to add this external jar to Project Structure:[image]
and it still didn't help.

Comment: change the working directory might help

Comment: mm... I'm looking for less aggressive solution

Comment: You may have several working folders. Do you have the source code of the vert.x cli class?

Comment: no :( I only have a jar

Comment: Make sure the main class you are trying to use is present in the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/working-with-module-dependencies.html).

Comment: I also added it to Modules (you can see the edited post). No Change

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertx-platform` as a dependency to your module (in your pom.xml), then run it and select your module as the classpath.

[image]

Comment: I changed Working Directory to "$MODULE_DIR$, but I didn't find anything but the name of my project at "Use classpath of module"

Comment: Well, is your module named the same as your project? And Working Directory has nothing to do with it.